# XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

There is an XML file . Roughly speaking it looks like this:

```
<DOCUMENT>
  .......
  <CONTENT>
    ......
    <PHASE>
      ......
      <INSTRUCTION>
        ......
        <VALUE><![CDATA[<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        arrayTitle = arrayTitle.concat([
        ["Выбор", "Выбор партии"],
        ["Всего на складе участка", "Всего на&nbspскладе участка"],
        ["№ технолог. серии", "№&nbspтехнолог. серии"],
        ["Подпись исполнителя /мастера", "Подпись&nbspисполнителя/ Подпись&nbspмастера"],
        ["Последн смена (последн расход)", "Последнее списание в&nbspсерии"]
        ]);</script>]]>
        </VALUE>
        ......

      </INSTRUCTION>
      ......
    </PHASE>
    ...... 
  </CONTENT>
......
<DOCUMENT>
```

I need to pull out all the XSLT and scripts are present in the form of an XML file :

```
<dict>
    <trans key="Выбор" value="Выбор партии" />
    <trans key="Всего на складе участка" value="Всего на складе участка" />
    <trans key="Ед.изм." value="Единицы измерения" />
    <trans key="№ технолог. серии" value="№ технолог. серии" />
    <trans key="Подпись исполнителя /мастера" value="Подпись исполнителя/ Подпись мастера" />
    <trans key="Последн смена (последн расход)" value="Последнее списание в серии" />
</dict>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not "write my code for me" site. Please show us the XSLT you have and we can try to help you.

Comment: XML file is very large . 3000 lines

Comment: An excerpt of the XML completed by your current XSLT would suffice to form a coherent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet tested with Saxon 9.7 EE, it makes use of the `analyze-string` function, the [`parse-json` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-parse-json) and then of the new [`array` type](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-arrays) in XPath 3.1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn array">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="DOCUMENT/CONTENT/PHASE/INSTRUCTION/VALUE"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="VALUE">
  <dict>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(.,  '\[.*\]', 's')//fn:match/parse-json(.)?*"/>
  </dict>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match=".[. instance of array(xs:string)]">
  <trans key="{.?1}" value="{.?2}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It transforms the input

```
<DOCUMENT>
  .......
  <CONTENT>
    ......
    <PHASE>
      ......
      <INSTRUCTION>
        ......
        <VALUE><![CDATA[<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        arrayTitle = arrayTitle.concat([
        ["Выбор", "Выбор партии"],
        ["Всего на складе участка", "Всего на&nbspскладе участка"],
        ["№ технолог. серии", "№&nbspтехнолог. серии"],
        ["Подпись исполнителя /мастера", "Подпись&nbspисполнителя/ Подпись&nbspмастера"],
        ["Последн смена (последн расход)", "Последнее списание в&nbspсерии"]
        ]);</script>]]>
        </VALUE>
        ......

      </INSTRUCTION>
      ......
    </PHASE>
    ...... 
  </CONTENT>
......
</DOCUMENT>
```

into the result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dict>
   <trans key="Выбор" value="Выбор партии"/>
   <trans key="Всего на складе участка" value="Всего на&amp;nbspскладе участка"/>
   <trans key="№ технолог. серии" value="№&amp;nbspтехнолог. серии"/>
   <trans key="Подпись исполнителя /мастера"
          value="Подпись&amp;nbspисполнителя/ Подпись&amp;nbspмастера"/>
   <trans key="Последн смена (последн расход)"
          value="Последнее списание в&amp;nbspсерии"/>
</dict>
```

To use the same approach with the open source Saxon 9.7 HE, we can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn array">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="DOCUMENT/CONTENT/PHASE/INSTRUCTION/VALUE"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="VALUE">
  <dict>
    <xsl:for-each select="analyze-string(.,  '\[.*\]', 's')//fn:match/parse-json(.)?*">
      <tans key="{.?1}" value="{.?2}"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </dict>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```